# What's the difference between casting and coercion in Python?

Tags: python, casting, types, coercion

In the Python documentation and on mailing lists I see that values are sometimes "cast", and sometimes "coerced".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think "casting" shouldn't be used for Python; there are only type conversion, but no casts (in the C sense). A type conversion is done e.g. through `int(o)` where the object o is converted into an integer (actually, an integer object is constructed out of o). Coercion happens in the case of binary operations: if you do `x+y`, and x and y have different types, they are coerced into a single type before performing the operation. In 2.x, a special method `__coerce__` allows object to control their coercion.

Answer (score 44):

Cast is explicit. Coerce is implicit.

The examples in Python would be:

```
cast(2, POINTER(c_float)) #cast
1.0 + 2  #coerce 
1.0 + float(2) #conversion
```

Cast really only comes up in the C FFI.  What is typically called casting in C or Java is referred to as conversion in python, though it often gets referred to as casting because of its similarities to those other languages.  In pretty much every language that I have experience with (including python) [Coercion](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0208/) is implicit type changing.

Comment: -1. That's C++ nomenclature; Python uses different terminology.

Comment: +1: For this question, the example is perfectly valid. And it's clearly marked as C++.

Comment: The question is about the term 'cast' in the context of the Python language.  The answer which explains that `float(1)` is construction, not casting, is better.

Comment: @CarlG It is an odd question, in the context of python cast doesn't really come up. The only place it is mentioned in the documentation is in the C interface where it refers to casts in C and ctypes where it refers to the ctypes.cast function.  The other answer is wrong about construction [float()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=float#float)  Is clearly called conversion, not construction.  Construction is never mentioned in the documentation for any of the built in conversion functions.